# How do I remove a duplicate package?

Tags: ros, 3rd-party-package, catkin, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed the velodyne driver package using

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-velodyne
```

But then I realised that the release version didn't support what I needed.
The current master branch however does.
https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne

I cloned the repository to my catkin workspace, made it then installed it.
However, when I try to launch it with

```
roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP16_points.launch
```

I get the error

```
[VLP16_points.launch] is neither a launch file in package [velodyne_pointcloud] nor is [velodyne_pointcloud] a launch file name
```

I think it's referencing the old package.
How do I remove the old package that I installed using sudo apt-get install?

Edit: Ran source command and outputted ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable

```
$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash   
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH  
/home/nathan/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

rospack find output

```
nathan:~/catkin_ws$ rospack find velodyne_pointcloud
/opt/ros/indigo/share/velodyne_pointcloud
```

catkin_make and catkin_install output

```
nathan:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/nathan/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/nathan/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/nathan/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _velodyne_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_VelodyneScan
Built target _velodyne_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_VelodynePacket
[  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddToInts
Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target bond_generate_messages_lisp
Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
Built target nodelet_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target bond_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_cpp
Built target nodelet_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
Built target bond_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  8%] Built target velodyne_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 11%] Built target velodyne_pointcloud_gencfg
[ 17%] Built target velodyne_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 22%] Built target velodyne_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 28%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp
[ 34%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_lisp
[ 34%] Built target velodyne_msgs_generate_messages
[ 45%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_py
[ 45%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages
[ 48%] Built target velodyne_input
[ 54%] Built target driver_nodelet
[ 60%] Built target velodyne_node
[ 71%] [ 71%] Built target ringcolors_node
Built target velodyne_rawdata
[ 77%] Built target ringcolors_nodelet
[ 94%] [ 94%] [ 94%] Built target cloud_node
Built target transform_node
[100%] Built target transform_nodelet
Built target cloud_nodelet
nathan:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make install
Base path: /home/nathan/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/nathan/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make install -j4 -l4" in "/home/nathan/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _velodyne_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_VelodyneScan
[  0%] Built target _velodyne_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_VelodynePacket
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddToInts
Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target bond_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_lisp
Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target bond_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_cpp
Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target bond_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target velodyne_pointcloud_gencfg
[  8%] Built target velodyne_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 28%] [ 28%] [ 28%] Built target velodyne_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_lisp
Built target velodyne_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 42%] [ 45%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp
Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_py
[ 45%] Built target velodyne_msgs_generate_messages
[ 48%] Built target velodyne_input
[ 48%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages
[ 54%] [ 60%] Built target velodyne_node
Built target driver_nodelet
[ 65%] Built target velodyne_rawdata
[ 71%] Built target ringcolors_node
[ 77%] Built target cloud_node
[ 82%] [ 88%] Built target cloud_nodelet
Built target ringcolors_nodelet
[ 94%] Built target transform_node
[100%] Built target transform_nodelet
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/_setup_util.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/env.sh
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/setup.sh
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/setup.zsh
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/.rosinstall
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne/package.xml
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_msgs/msg/VelodynePacket.msg
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_msgs/msg/VelodyneScan.msg
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_msgs/cmake/velodyne_msgs-msg-paths.cmake
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/velodyne_msgs
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/velodyne_msgs/VelodynePacket.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan.h
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/velodyne_msgs
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/velodyne_msgs/msg
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/velodyne_msgs/msg/VelodyneScan.lisp
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/velodyne_msgs/msg/_package_VelodyneScan.lisp
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/velodyne_msgs/msg/_package_VelodynePacket.lisp
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/velodyne_msgs/msg/velodyne_msgs-msg.asd
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/velodyne_msgs/msg/_package.lisp
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/velodyne_msgs/msg/VelodynePacket.lisp
Listing /home/nathan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_msgs ...
Listing /home/nathan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_msgs/msg ...
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_msgs
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_msgs/__init__.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_msgs/__init__.pyc
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_msgs/msg
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_msgs/msg/__init__.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_msgs/msg/_VelodyneScan.pyc
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_msgs/msg/_VelodynePacket.pyc
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_msgs/msg/_VelodynePacket.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_msgs/msg/__init__.pyc
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_msgs/msg/_VelodyneScan.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/pkgconfig/velodyne_msgs.pc
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_msgs/cmake/velodyne_msgs-msg-extras.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_msgs/cmake/velodyne_msgsConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_msgs/cmake/velodyne_msgsConfig-version.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_msgs/package.xml
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials/msg/Num.msg
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials/srv/AddToInts.srv
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials/cmake/beginner_tutorials-msg-paths.cmake
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/beginner_tutorials
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/beginner_tutorials/AddToIntsRequest.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/beginner_tutorials/AddToInts.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/beginner_tutorials/AddToIntsResponse.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/beginner_tutorials/Num.h
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/beginner_tutorials
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/beginner_tutorials/srv
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/beginner_tutorials/srv/_package_AddToInts.lisp
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/beginner_tutorials/srv/beginner_tutorials-srv.asd
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/beginner_tutorials/srv/AddToInts.lisp
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/beginner_tutorials/srv/_package.lisp
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/beginner_tutorials/msg
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/beginner_tutorials/msg/beginner_tutorials-msg.asd
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/beginner_tutorials/msg/_package_Num.lisp
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/beginner_tutorials/msg/Num.lisp
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/common-lisp/ros/beginner_tutorials/msg/_package.lisp
Listing /home/nathan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials ...
Listing /home/nathan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg ...
Listing /home/nathan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/srv ...
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/__init__.py
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/srv
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/srv/__init__.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/srv/_AddToInts.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/srv/__init__.pyc
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/srv/_AddToInts.pyc
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/__init__.pyc
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg/__init__.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg/_Num.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg/_Num.pyc
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/beginner_tutorials/msg/__init__.pyc
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/pkgconfig/beginner_tutorials.pc
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials/cmake/beginner_tutorials-msg-extras.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials/cmake/beginner_tutorialsConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials/cmake/beginner_tutorialsConfig-version.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/beginner_tutorials/package.xml
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/pkgconfig/velodyne_driver.pc
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_driver/cmake/velodyne_driverConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_driver/cmake/velodyne_driverConfig-version.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_driver/package.xml
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/velodyne_driver
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/velodyne_driver/input.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/velodyne_driver/ring_sequence.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_driver/nodelet_velodyne.xml
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_driver/launch
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_driver/launch/nodelet_manager.launch
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/velodyne_driver/vdump
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/libvelodyne_input.so
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/velodyne_driver/velodyne_node
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/libdriver_nodelet.so
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/velodyne_pointcloud/VelodyneConfigConfig.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_pointcloud/__init__.py
Listing /home/nathan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_pointcloud/cfg ...
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_pointcloud/cfg
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_pointcloud/cfg/__init__.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_pointcloud/cfg/VelodyneConfigConfig.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_pointcloud/cfg/__init__.pyc
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/velodyne_pointcloud/cfg/VelodyneConfigConfig.pyc
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/pkgconfig/velodyne_pointcloud.pc
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/cmake/velodyne_pointcloudConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/cmake/velodyne_pointcloudConfig-version.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/package.xml
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/velodyne_pointcloud
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/velodyne_pointcloud/calibration.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/velodyne_pointcloud/rawdata.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/include/velodyne_pointcloud/point_types.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/nodelets.xml
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/launch
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/launch/VLP16_points.launch
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/launch/transform_nodelet.launch
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/launch/32e_points.launch
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/launch/cloud_nodelet.launch
-- Installing: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/params
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/params/32db.yaml
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/params/VLP16db.yaml
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/params/64e_utexas.yaml
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/params/rviz_points.vcg
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/share/velodyne_pointcloud/params/64e_s2.1-sztaki.yaml
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/velodyne_pointcloud/gen_calibration.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/libvelodyne_rawdata.so
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/velodyne_pointcloud/cloud_node
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/libcloud_nodelet.so
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/velodyne_pointcloud/ringcolors_node
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/libringcolors_nodelet.so
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/velodyne_pointcloud/transform_node
-- Up-to-date: /home/nathan/catkin_ws/install/lib/libtransform_nodelet.so
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224960/how-do-i-remove-a-duplicate-package?/) by [nadnav](https://answers.ros.org/users/25715/nadnav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your catkin workspace had been constructed correctly, the driver built from source should *overlay* the binary package you had installed previously. At this point, you'd probably have to re-create the workspace from scratch, being *very* careful to source only the ROS distro while doing it.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you `source`d the `setup.*sh` file in your Catkin workspace (cf. [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment#Create_a_ROS_Workspace))?

If you think you did, we may not have enough info. Edit your question to add `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` command output.

UPDATE) If you are using `install` space, then `source ~/catkin_ws/installl/setup.bash`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2016-01-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nadnav](https://answers.ros.org/users/25715/nadnav/) on 2016-01-24**:
Yes, I've sourced the setup.bash file. I've also added the source command to my bashrc so it should be running it automatically. However, I just ran the source command again just to be 100% confident. I've edited my original question with the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-01-24**:
How about:

```
rospack find velodyne_pointcloud
```

You might want to paste all output when you did "make". Make sure the package was built without outstanding errors.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-01-24**:\

> How do I remove the old package that I installed using sudo apt-get install?

Despite that's not even a ROS question, you can remove by `apt-get purge` %PKGNAME%.

**Comment by [nadnav](https://answers.ros.org/users/25715/nadnav/) on 2016-01-24**:
I've updated the original post with the rospack find and catkin_make output.